# Parse and Sort JSON data using java

Tags: java, json, sorting

I am looking to parse the following array using org.json.simple library and having difficulty. Could someone please look at my json file and code and advise what I am doing wrong

```
{
  "Company": [
{
  "Department": "Engineering",
  "Employee": [
    {
      "EmpName": "Jack",
      "EmpCode": "8",
      "Type": "Permanent"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "John",
      "EmpCode": "45",
      "Type": "Permanent"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Ron",
      "EmpCode": "9",
      "Type": "Contract"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Jin",
      "EmpCode": "6",
      "Type": "Permanent"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Jill",
      "EmpCode": "",
      "Type": "Retired"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Sam",
      "EmpCode": "89",
      "Type": "Permanent"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Jonathan",
      "EmpCode": "66",
      "Type": "Permanent"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Craig",
      "EmpCode": "",
      "Type": "Ex-Employee"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Son Hui",
      "EmpCode": "4",
      "Type": "Permanent"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Joshua",
      "EmpCode": "12",
      "Type": "Contract"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Tulip",
      "EmpCode": "70",
      "Type": "Contract"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "Department": "IT",
  "Employee": [
    {
      "EmpName": "Nico",
      "EmpCode": "50",
      "Type": "Resigned"
    }, {
      "EmpName": "Phil",
      "EmpCode": "103",
      "Type": "Resigned"
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}
```

Notice that a few EmpCode fields are also blank. How should I handle them. Also, I need to be able to re-arrange the data while displaying it, I mean I need to sort the data based on EmpCode or Type.

The code I wrote to parse the above json is mentioned below:

```
package amazontesting;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class json {
    private static final String filePath = /emp.json";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Department");
        //String suites = (String) jsonObject.get("Company");


        JSONArray slideContent = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Department");
        Iterator i = slideContent.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
            String title = (String) jsonObject.get("Employee");
            System.out.println(title);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {}
    catch(IOException e)
    {}
    catch(ParseException e)
    {}

    }
}
```

Comment: "Advise what I'm doing wrong" is not a suitable question for SO.  Please describe exactly what issue you're having, what you've done to diagnose the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, the JSON referred to in the code does not sound like the posted JSON.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, about the incorrect JSON references, I have updated those now. I am new to handling JSON, so I read on the internet and tried to play around with sample codes. Some posts mentioned I should create a class based on the json and then call it in the main class, whereas some mentioned that the above code would do the trick. I tried to run this code and department prints null.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have misunderstanding of how Json structure works and what kind of objects it's may contains.

For example, what do you think you do in this piece of code?

```
JSONArray slideContent = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Department");
Iterator i = slideContent.iterator();
```

Looks like you trying to get json object with name "Department", but it's not an JsonArray, it's a String.

```
"Department": "Engineering"
//Writing code "jsonObject.get("Department")" 
//you will get string "Engineering"

//this code will be correct
(JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Employee")
//because a json value for name "Employee" it's an JsonArray
```

Comment: I am assuming this creates an array with all employees under Department

Comment: It's will get you value for a name "Department", and the value it's a string "Engineering"

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'll do a little more reading on this